# Flatten a PHP array on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have this array:

```
 {
  "text": {
       "3": "asdsadad",
       "4": "123123"
  },
  "textarea": {
       "5": "45655656",
       "6": "89879879789"
  },
  "file": {
       "2": {}
  }
 }
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
   {
    "3": "asdsadad",
    "4": "123123"
    "5": "45655656",
    "6": "89879879789"
    "2": {}
   }
```

Comment: The duplicate answer is not really a Laravel answer, which **does** exist: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-flatten

Comment: @ThomasMoors although the `array_flatten` function does not preserve keys.

Comment: Use the power of collections! if $arr is your array as noted above: *collect($arr)->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return collect($item)->each(function($value, $key) {
                return [$key => $value];
            });*
        })->toArray();